# Was this subscription initialized?

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactional-replication

Running SQL 2008...

Where can I find in the SQL dB or how can I determine if a transactional subscription was initialized when it was created??

AHIA,

LarryR...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is from my post on another message board (click here)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreplication/thread/41abf696-635c-4e43-a32c-5ecdde79e61d/)

```
SELECT p.name [Pub Name], a.name [Article Name],srvname [Destionation Server], dest_db [Destination dB], login_name [Created by],
case sync_type
    when 1 then 'Automatic'
    when 2 then 'NONE'
end Sync_Type,
case nosync_type
    when 0 then 'automatic (snapshot)'
    when 1 then 'Not Initialized'
    when 2 then 'initialize with backup'
    when 3 then 'initialize from log sequence number (LSN)'
end [Init Type]
 FROM dbo.syssubscriptions s
 left join dbo.sysarticles a on s.artid = a.artid 
 left join dbo.syspublications p on a.pubid = p.pubid
```

LarryR....